# Webbrowser not loading page content on Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, windows-phone-8

I'm building somewhat of a caching mechanism for some webpages, so that if the webpage is already stored in IsolatedStorage, then it's not necessary to fetch it online. However, when I'm loading the page, the content (CSS, js, images) aren´t being loaded, although the files are already in the appropriate paths and the paths in the files all seem correct.

When I try using a very simple html with just an image in it, the content is loaded properly.

The more complex webpages have multiple sub-directories but all the paths to the content seem to be pointing correctly.

Any ideas on what may be happening? I've tried pretty much everything I've found on google, with no success. Is this just another buggy issue of the Webbrowser control on WP8 that I'm not aware of? I'd really appreciate if you have any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's see some code...

Comment: Thank you webfrogs but I've managed to fix the problem. It was due to the  the fact that the html main file was not at the root of the folder structure.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. Apparently the main html file needs to be at the root of the folders' structure. Would be nice to have that information on the official msdn page. Hope at least this helps anyone that may have the same problem when loading local pages.

Thanks!